# Free alternate to sharepoint portal?

Tags: sharepoint, content-management-system, content-management

Would anyone like to recommend free alternative to SharePoint Portal ?

We want to create a internal portal site for Content Management with features like Permissions, History etc.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096392/any-good-alternative-for-sharepoint-ofcourse-opensource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetNuke ([www.dotnetnuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com)) is a great one.  You could also check out Alfresco ([www.alfresco.com](http://www.alfresco.com))

Answer (score 2):

If you have windows 2003 server sharepoint services comes for free.. This is ok if you have a small team around 40 people.. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb848085.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The WhiteHouse.org site just moved its CMS to [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) - so it's at least good enough for government work. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) is an open source CMS with Web Content Management that is often positioned as Open Source Alternative to SharePoint .  Used by lots of enterprises all over the world (check customers list).   Here is [one comparison.](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/enterprise-cms/sharepoint-vs-alfresco-a-platform-perspective-004549.php) from content management analysts.